# Как радиальный градиент figma перевести в css?

Tags: css, градиент, figma

В figma есть квадрат (я не дизайнер и не фронтендер, так что точно объяснтить не могу как он создан), на него наложен радиальный градиент. Перетаскиваю градиент следующим образом - центр ставлю на середину правой грани, вторую точку прямой направляющей градиента ставлю на середину нижней грани, точку которая лежит на перпендикулярной прямой и отвечает за приплюснутость градиента ставлю на середину верхней грани. Если перейти в режим разработчика то фигма превращает это в следующий css:

```
background: radial-gradient(70.71% 70.71% at 100% 50%, #EFF4F5 0%, #C1C4C6 100%);
```

Если укорачивать перпендикулярную линию, то первое число в CSS уменьшается:

```
background: radial-gradient(47.17% 70.71% at 100% 50%, #EFF4F5 0%, #C1C4C6 100%);
```

Структуру данного фрейма мы получаем по api, и градиент в ответе описывается следующим образом:

```
{
  "blendMode": "NORMAL",
  "type": "GRADIENT_RADIAL",
  "gradientHandlePositions": [
    {
      "x": 1.0000001490116865,
      "y": 0.5000002682209939
    },
    {
      "x": 0.5000001490116759,
      "y": 1.0000002086163384
    },
    {
      "x": 0.4999999701976776, // это не грани, для укороченной линии приходит 0.6879759173955349
      "y": 2.9802318834981634e-8 // это на грани, для укороченной линии приходит 0.18797598797746545
    }
  ],
  "gradientStops": [
    // ...
  ]
}
```

По всей видимости элементы в gradientHandlePositions описаны в относительных величинах от высоты и ширины квадрата. Первый элемент описывает центр градиента (и из него наглядно получается часть `at 100% 50%` из css), второй описывает конец направляющей градиента, а третий описывает точку на перпендикулярной прямой которая регулирует приплюснутость градиент. Но как мне из этих координат получить `(47.17% 70.71% at` - я зависимости не вижу.

Comment: `background-image: radial-gradient([ circle ||` **`<радиус> ] [ at`** `<позиция> ]?` радиус - длинна от цента. полный синтаксис радиального градиента можете глянуть тут: https://webref.ru/css/value/radial-gradient